# merge two array list of object with structure fields in first array

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I have two array list of object and i need fill object element in first array list from some of field object element from second array list and this project need best performance please guide me for best way for solve this problem .

first array list's object structure `ArrayList <SellProductAmountDTO>` and 
fill OrderProductDTO object with conditional sellContractId field of SellProductAmountDTO with id of SellContractProduct.

```
public class SellProductAmountDTO {
    private Long sellContractId;
    private Long amount;
    private OrderProductDTO orderProduct;
    //getter ans setters
}
```

and OrderProductDTO stucture :

```
public class OrderProductDTO {
    private List<Long> costGroupId;
    private Long productId;
}
```

and second array list's object stucture `ArrayList<SellContractProduct>`:

```
public class SellContractProduct{

    private Long id;

    private Long rateGroupId;

    private Long currencyRateGroupId;

    private Set<BuyType> buyTypes;

    private Consumption consumption;

    private Long productId;

    private SellContractCustomer sellContractCustomer;

    private Set<Depot> depots = new HashSet<>();

    private List<Long> costGroupIds;

    private List<Long> currencyIds;

    //getter and setters
}
```

Comment: Could you try a little harder to explain your question? I can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: SellContractProduct list is full and i will fill OrderProductDTO's costGroupId and productId from SellContractProduct with conditional SellContractProduct's id with SellProductAmountDTO's sellContractId

Comment: Provide some initial code showing what you try to do and the size of the lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this should work:

```
List<SellProductAmountDTO> sellProductAmountDTOList = new ArrayList<>(); // this should be full
List<SellContractProduct> sellContractProductList = new ArrayList<>(); // this should be full

// build a stream on array 2 to use in the for loop
Stream<SellContractProduct> SellContractProductListStream = sellContractProductList.stream();

for(SellProductAmountDTO sellProductAmountDTO : sellProductAmountDTOList) {
    // find the correct SellContractProduct
    Optional<SellContractProduct> productOption = SellContractProductListStream
            .filter(sellContactProduct -> sellContactProduct.getId().equals(sellProductAmountDTO.getSellContractId()))
            .findFirst();

    // if the SellContractProduct was found, then set its values into the sellProductAmountDTO's order product
    if(productOption.isPresent()) {
        sellProductAmountDTO.getOrderProduct().setProductId(productOption.get().getId());
        sellProductAmountDTO.getOrderProduct().setCostGroupId(productOption.get().getCostGroupIds());
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Might have better performance with a map

```
List<SellProductAmountDTO> sellProductAmountDTOList = new ArrayList<>(); // this should be full
List<SellContractProduct> sellContractProductList = new ArrayList<>(); // this should be full

// make a map listing contracts by their Id
Map<Long, SellContractProduct> SellContractProductMap = sellContractProductList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(SellContractProduct::getId, Function.identity()));

for(SellProductAmountDTO sellProductAmountDTO : sellProductAmountDTOList) {
    // find the correct SellContractProduct in the map
    SellContractProduct product = SellContractProductMap.get(sellProductAmountDTO.getSellContractId());

    if(product != null) {
        sellProductAmountDTO.getOrderProduct().setProductId(product.getId());
        sellProductAmountDTO.getOrderProduct().setCostGroupId(product.getCostGroupIds());
    }
}
```